# appMobi iOS build failure "An error occured while building the application. Verify your build assets are correct"

Tags: ios, html, appmobi, app-hub

So I am attempting to build an adHoc version of my app for iOS to test on. However about a minute into the build I get an error

"An error occured while building the application. Verify your build assets are correct"

Not sure what this means, how what asset is apparently missing. I've walked through the entire guide to do it that appMobi provides. I have verified all my assets are in place to the best of my knowledge, and yet it fails. Whats worse is appHub indicates iOS builds are green to build.. and even worse is I can build an Android apk off the same bundle without fail.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my answer to this a long while back. I should have answered it to help keep others informed. The problem ended up being that I was using the wrong certs, unfortunately there was no distinct way to find that out. It took the appMobi/phonegap staff looking into it from the back end to find out that the cert was the wrong type. But in the end I got myself the right certificate, and plugged it in, and it built just fine